# Distinguishing homology $S^1 \times S^2$'s which bound homotopy $S^1$'s

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Due to Mazur, Akbulut and Kirby  and many others, there are many examples of integer homology 3-spheres which bound contractible 4-manifolds given by attaching a single 2-handle to $S^1 \times D^3$ which algebraically intersects the one-handle once but maybe geometrically many times. Many of these can be distinguished from the 3-sphere by things like the Casson invariant and other invariants specifically developed for integral homology $S^3$'s for instance in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.01491.pdf

I would like to know how to distinguish the analogous constructions (which don't reduce to the above case) for homology $S^1 \times S^2$'s bounding homotopy $S^1 \times D^3$'s (homotopy equivalent not homeomorphic). Specifically are there any examples of knots in $S^1\times S^2 \# S^1 \times S^2$ which algebraically intersect both one handles once but not geometrically, that surger to (hopefully many or even infinitely for the application I have in mind) non-trivial examples of homology $S^1 \times S^2$'s? And if so, how does one distinguish these?

Note by construction these all bound homotopy $S^1 \times D^3$'s. It's very easy to draw such candidates knots, but they end up having a decent amount of crossings, and even then I don't know what tools I would use to distinguish their surgeries from $S^1 \times S^2$ or each other.

Comment: There's two aspects (in my mind) to your question: distinguishing homology $S^1\times S^2$'s, and distinguishing the 4-manifolds (homotopy $S^1$) that a homology $S^1\times S^2$ bounds. Which one are you having issues with?

Comment: @IanAgol I would like to do the first. I want to have examples analogous to Mazur manifolds (homotopy equivalent 4-manifolds which are distinguished by their boundary) that hopefully can be described in the simplest possible way (surgery on a single knot in $S^1 \times S^2 \# S^1 \times S^2$).

Comment: There are plenty of tools for distinguishing 3-manifolds in practice. See the website http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~nmd/computop/   Snappea is particularly effective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A standard construction would be to take a 3-manifold $Y$ given by 0-surgery on a knot $K$. If $K$ is the boundary of a slice disk $D \subset B^4$, then the complement, say $W$ of a neighborhood of $D$ is a homology $S^1 \times B^3$ with boundary $Y$. But you are asking for more, since $W$ should be a homotopy $S^1 \times B^3$; this is equivalent to its fundamental group being ${\bf Z}$. This would require that the Alexander polynomial of $K$ be equal to $1$.

There are plenty of examples of Alexander polynomial 1 knots bounding a disk with $\pi_1(B^4-D) = \bf{Z}$. Three nice ones are given in the paper [Doubly slice knots with low crossing number](http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2015/21-47v.pdf) (New York J. Math. 21 (2015) 1007–1026) of Livingston and Meier. See section 4.2.

If you are willing to accept a topological (rather than smooth) $W$, then Freedman has shown any homology $S^1 \times S^2$ with Alexander polynomial equal to 1 bounds such a $W$. Lots of $S^1 \times S^2$s with Alexander polynomial equal to 1 do not bound a smooth homotopy $S^1 \times B^3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the three from the Livingston and Meier paper are of the type I want (the slice disk exterior is diffeomorphic to a boundary sum of two $S^1 \times B^3$'s with a single 2-handle attached).

Comment: I second @IanAgol's suggestion to use Snappea to distinguish the resulting 3-manifolds.

Comment: I think you likely already realized this, but in case anyone else is reading this the examples you gave are already distinguished from $S^1 \times S^2$ by property R.

Comment: I read the question as asking about distinguishing these from each other. You're quite right that Property R implies that none of them is $S^1\times S^2$.