# Bipartedly slice links and their surgeries

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, surgery-theory

A link L in $S^3$ is said to be *strongly slice* if $L=∂D$,where $D$ is a disjoint union of smoothly and properly embedded disks in $B^4$.

A link $L$ in $S^3$ is called *bipartedly slice* if $L = L_1 \cup L_2$, where $L_1$, $L_2$ are strongly slice links.

These are the examples. For the third picture, $L_1$ is the union of two unknots.

[image]

I have question about the generalization of [Ruberman](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248783/distinguishing-homology-s1-times-s2s-which-bound-homotopy-s1s/248823#248823)'s answer:

Suppose we have a bipartedly slice link $L$ in $S^3$. Let $Y$ be $3$-manifold obtained by $0$-surgery on $L$. Let $D \subset B^4$ be the union of slice disk bounded by $L$.

Let $W$ be slice disk exterior $4$-manifold, i.e., $W = B^4 \setminus D$. Are they true that

1. $\partial W = Y$?
2. $H_*(W, \mathbb Z ) = H_*(S^1 \times B^3, \mathbb Z)$?
3. Say $L$ has $n$-components. If we attach $n$ times integer framed $2$-handles to $W$, then do we obtain a contractible manifold $X$?

Comment: I'm a little confused: why are the slice discs disjoint?  In your definition of bipartedly slice, $L_1$ has slice discs, and $L_2$ has slice discs, but if you put them together, they may intersect.

Comment: i.e. $W$ is not a slice disc exterior.

Comment: The argument of Ruberman seems to be generalized when the case that link is strongly slice, right?

Comment: Is there any easy example for slice disks that intersect?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.   Rather than having all the discs on one side of $B^4$, you can put $L_1$ on one side, and $L_2$ on the other side of $S^3$ in $S^4$, i.e. you would be modifying two different $B^4$ manifolds.  Or you could view it as you are  drilling the $L_1$ $2$-handles, and attaching the $L_2$ $2$-handles to a $D^4$.